# How to Install liferay sdk on netbean8?

Tags: java, netbeans, liferay, portlet, netbeans-8

I try install liferay sdk on netbeans IDE.

I have downloed portalpack v 3.0.5 pack from [this Link](https://contrib.netbeans.org/portalpack/)
and imported it in netbeans through netbeans>Tools>Plugins all of them have installed except "org-netbeans-modules-portalpack-portlets-spring.nbm" and show below Warning and after that doesn't change anything in netbeans new projet and I can't see "new portlet" or "liferay project" inside netbeans new project.

[image]

How can fix it?

Jdk version = 8

OS = windows 8

Netbeans IDE Version = 8

Liferay version=6.2 Ga

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm getting the same error, but found workaround.
To generate Liferay project (e.g. portlet) on Netbeans 8 go "File --> New Project" choose Maven category, "Project from Archetype" project. Push Next. In Search input write "liferay portlet". Here you can choose archetype.